# How to generate a report in a nuget package every time a build is run?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nuget, roslyn

I have built a roslyn analyzer and packaged it into a nuget package. If someone installs this package, how can I log some piece of information every time their build runs? For example, I want to create a file and store it somewhere in the user's project directory, and update that file every time the build runs.

I've tried to research this issue but everything I'm seeing doesn't make this an automatic process (i.e., the user has to do their own logging).

Unfortunately, I can't show my code (due to an NDA), but if the reports work with the template roslyn analyzer in Visual Studio, it'll work for me too.

Comment: Do you mean everytime the compilation updates (which could be several times a second if they are typing) or only when they run the "Build" command from visual studio / msbuild.exe from the commandline?

Comment: I mean just when they build from visual studio or run msbuild

Comment: Analyzers are not notified of user-initiated builds. you should look into writing a [custom MSBuild Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing) and including it with your nuget package if this is something you want to be able to do.

Comment: Can I just add the task as another project alongside the analyzer in the same solution, or is there a different way to pack them together into a nuget package?

Comment: packaging an msbuild task in the same nuget package should be possible but you will likly need a third "Packaging" project that references both your analyzer project and your msbuild task project. See this blog post by Nate for some guidance: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/07/05/msbuild-task-in-nuget/#package-layout

Comment: Thank you Jonathon, I'm very new to this kind of stuff and your posts are very helpful! I'll let you know if I have any other questions